# Lock table size issue when deleting on MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-8.0

I'm attempting to delete errant records from a table based on certain dates and running into the following error:

```
mysql> delete from myTable where dataDate in ('2011-07-12');
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

The table doesn't yet have indexes (this is post-load clean-up), and consists of ~2B records:

```
mysql> select table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'myTable';
+------------+
| table_rows |
+------------+
| 2073294315 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.51 sec)
```

Suggestions I found via search suggested upping `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but I've already upped default pool size by 8x in order to get the data to load in reasonable time and current sits at 512MB:

```
mysql> select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
+---------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size |
+---------------------------+
|                1073741824 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm planning to reload data for 3 dates (~3M records) after deleting the errant records.  Wondering if I should index the table first or if there are other adjustments that will allow this.

Comment: how much ram do you have available?- because 1G is small (how much does your phone have), especially if your deleting lots of records afrom a moderate table.  How many records are being deleted? `select count(*)  from myTable where dataDate in ('2011-07-12');` Is `dataDate` at the beginning of any of the indexes (assumed not based on your indexing question)? How often are you planning to reload? Do you have any other date related queries against this data that would use this index?

Comment: Hi @danblack, 16G total, about 8G available.  Single date constitutes ~1M records, haven't done any kind of processing against the data yet.

Comment: You may try to delete with chunks - `delete from myTable where dataDate in ('2011-07-12') LIMIT ?????;` until affected rows=0. In SP...

Comment: @Akina, how would I process the 2nd, 3rd, nth chunk in that case?

Comment: Is this even using InnoDB ? .. if a delete exceeds lock-table size .. it kinda smells strongly for MyIsam ..

Answer (score 1):

Schematically (draft code!):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_until_done()
BEGIN
DECLARE records_count_before BIGINT;
DECLARE records_count_after BIGINT;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable INTO records_count_after;
cycle: LOOP
    SET records_count_before = records_count_after;
    DELETE FROM myTable WHERE dataDate IN ('2011-07-12') LIMIT 10000;
    /* SELECT SLEEP(1) INTO records_count_after; */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable INTO records_count_after;
    IF records_count_before <= records_count_after THEN
        LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END
```

It is safe to add SELECT into some service table for some flag value which stops the operation. For example this can be a delay value (SLEEP argument) - its change may change deletion speed and server loading during it, and the value above some predefined value (or maybe zero) is a signal to leave cycle and stop the deletion operation unconditionally.

---

Simplified code according to [danblack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack)'s recommendation:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_until_done()
BEGIN
REPEAT
    /* SELECT SLEEP(1) INTO @dummy; */
    DELETE FROM myTable WHERE dataDate IN ('2011-07-12') LIMIT 10000;
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() 
END REPEAT;
END
```

Comment: Or use `ROW_COUNT() = 0` to determine the end of the loop.

Comment: @danblack Thanks, updated. (I don't like ROW_COUNT() reflexively, so I often forget about it...).

Comment: simplifies it more that I thought (probably lack of stored procedure writing experience). nit - enabling the `SLEEP` causes `ROW_COUNT()` to return -1 so reordering the statements.

Comment: @danblack That's why I do not like indirect methods... updated.

Comment: NO.  Without `INDEX(dataDate), the `DELETE` will take longer and longer.  Each `SELECT COUNT(*)` will do a full table scan.

Comment: @RickJames *Each `SELECT COUNT(*)` will do a full table scan.* COUNT(*) without any WHERE takes the result from primary key statistic it seems...

Comment: @Akina - MyISAM dead-reckons `COUNT(*)`, so it is instant.  What version are you using?  (I have heard rumors that InnoDB and/or MariaDB will do the equivalent for InnoDB.)

Answer (score 0):

- Based on 8G available, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G`.
- If you are using MyISAM, switch to InnoDB.
- Do add the index.  It is usually faster to add it after populating the table.  (Still, it will take a long time unless you have 8.0.)
- See this for multiple techniques for bulk deletion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig
- Phrase the test thus:  `dataDate = '2011-07-12'`
- If `dataDate` is a `DATETIME`, then you need a range test.
- `SELECT SLEEP(1);` does not need an `INTO` clause.